# iOS 13 Background Uploading Error : Trying to upload upto 500 images to AWS server

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, background, ios13

I am trying to upload 500 images to AWS server while app is in background but background task is not running more than 2 minutes in iOS 13.
Below is the AWS uploading code:-

```
        let  transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
        let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()

        expression.progressBlock = {(task, progress) in DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            // Do something e.g. Update a progress bar.

        })
        }
        var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock?

        completionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                if let error = error {

                    failure(error as NSError)
                }
                else{
                    print("Upload complete")
                }
            })
        }

        transferUtility.uploadData(data,
                                   bucket: "S3bucketname",
                                   key: "keyname",
                                   contentType:"image extension",
                                   expression: expression,
                                   completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith {
                                    (task) -> AnyObject? in
                                    if let error = task.error {
                                        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                    }
                                    if let result = task.result {
                                        print("this is result \(result)")

                                    }
                                    if  task.isCompleted {
                                        print("task complete")
                                    }

                                    return nil;
        }
```

Comment: i think this is an Apple restriction - you cannot upload "infinitely" - you just get a certain amount of time, if your task is not done then, you have to think about your task...and solve it in another way ...e.g. when the app is running. Or upload maybe 50 pics in the first background task....and the next 50 in the next background task run.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on a background process to do this. You should use a background `URLSession` so that the transfer is handled by iOS itself.  Even then you shouldn't expect 500 images to be uploaded very quickly.

Comment: @Paulw11 AWS api itself using 'URLSession' for uploading images.

Comment: You can plan your operations give some time after every success upload.

Comment: @Jain_Taresh you need to see if there is an option for it to use a [background session configuration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1407496-background)otherwise you may need to write your own code that does rather than using the AWS library.

Comment: @Jain_Taresh This uses background sessions, but have you implemented [`application(_:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622941-application)? See https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/1047

Comment: @Rob I already implement this delegate method, it will be called too late sometimes after 2 minute or sometimes after 5 or 6 minute. After 2 or 3 times this delegate method doesn't call anymore in background.

Comment: With background [`NSURLSessionConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1407496-backgroundsessionconfigurationwi?language=objc), which this library uses, the request should just carry on, not subject to any 3 minute limitation. Re the app not waking up in the background, that can happen if you force-quit the app, or you violated the background operation rules (e.g. you started background task and let it timeout without ever calling the completion handler). I wonder if there is some unrelated behavior in your app that might be affecting it.